# Show that there is a unique continuous function

Tags: banach-algebras

[image]

I have no idea where to even start, i have never dealt with question like this before, any direction you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set $tx=a$,then $x\partial {t}=\partial {a}$,do the replacements and then derivate the relation and find $f$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Consider the operator

$$T \colon C([0,1]) \to C([0,1]);\quad T(f) \colon x \mapsto x^2 + \int_0^1 t^2f(tx)\,dt.$$

Show that this operator satisfies the hypotheses of Banach's fixed point theorem.

Comment: My partial result is

|T(f)-T(g)|= int(t^2(f(tx)-g(tx))

is that ok so far?\

Comment: That's a good start. Now estimate $\lvert f(tx) - g(tx)\rvert$.

Comment: Won't this be dependent on the norm i choose? However, i am geussing that  |f(tx)-g(tx)| <= norm|f-g|.  How am i to know which norm to choose?

Comment: Actually, isnt f(tx) at most 1 and g(tx) at most 1? So, wouldnt that mean that |f(tx)- g(tx)| <= 1

Comment: Unless explicitly stated otherwise, always use the $\sup$-norm, $\lVert f\rVert = \sup \{\lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in [a,b]\}$ on $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Thanks, so that means that i should get T(f)-T(g) <= norm(f-g)*int(t^2) = norm(f-g)*9

Comment: @greg No, $f(tx)$ can be arbitrarily large, $f$ can be any continuous function. But $\lvert f(tx) - g(tx)\rvert$ is bounded by the norm of $f-g$.

Comment: @greg $\int_0^1 t^2\,dt =$? Not $9$.

Comment: OMG LOL! yeah i understood my mistake. its 1/3 so then taking the max t value. i think we should obtain, |T(f)-T(g)| = (1\3)*norm(f-g) which means that it is a contraction and so now we can use the banach fixed point theorem. So that we obtain, 
f(t) = x^2 + int t^2f(tx)dt and this is enough to prove the existence. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. It proves not only existence, also uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks alot, i really appreciate it. I hate it when i make silly mistakes!

Comment: @greg Everybody does (make silly mistakes, and hate making them).